# traceroute syntax error in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to python and am now learning about 'traceroute'. I don't exactly understand how this works. If I am typing the traceroute in python command line, I receive a syntax error:

```
traceroute www.somewebsite.com
```

I receive a syntax error pointing to ^www

Am I misunderstanding or doing something wrong? I'm trying to work on this in practice from a book reading assignment.

Can someone explain what traceroute is exactly?
Your help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: [traceroute](http://linux.die.net/man/8/traceroute) is a command. You have to invoke it from the shell, not from the Python interpreter.

Comment: I think you have your books confused...

Comment: If you're using `ipython`, prefix the command with a `!`. I can't really think of any other scenarios where this actually makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

This is not supposed to work, because python does not understand terminal/cmd commands. So you need to use `os.system` in this case:

So, in your case:

```
import os
os.system('traceroute www.somewebsite.com`)
```

In windows its `tracert` not `traceroute`.